# Finding Closed form solution

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, exponentiation

I am struggling to find a closed form solution to the following equation:
$$
\ln\left(1+knxe^{\left(-kx\right)}\right)-ne^{\left(-kx\right)}=0
$$
for some constants $k>0$ and $n>0$. I have been looking into the Lambert W function but don't see how this would help here. Is it necessary to resort to linearization of the logarithm or some other sort of approximation method? I am mostly just interested in the dependence of $x$ on $k$.

Comment: Have a look at my edit

Comment: I am devasted. See the remark of @g.kov following my answer : I don't know how I have overlooked the presence of a supplementary $x$ in the parenthesis...

Comment: Well, if you just interested in the dependence of $x$ on $k$,
let's assume that you can solve this equation
as $xk=f(n)$. Then for constant $n$ 
the value of $x$ would be inversely 
proportional to $k$.

Comment: @g.kov I completely missed that fact, and it will definitely come in use with some of my analysis. The approach of Jean Marie and Claude also is very promising for me, though I will try to adjust to include the supplementary x

Comment: Have a look at what I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Setting $X=kx$, and $Y=n$, we get the implicit equation:

$$\operatorname{ln}(1+XYe^{-X})=Ye^{-X}$$

Matlab gives a plot (black line) in complete agreement with the plot by @g.cov.

Then I have attempted to fit a "simple" function chosen among the classical fitting functions, and found by trial and error a rather good agreement by taking (red curve):

$$Y=0.328 X^2e^{0.774 X}$$

otherwise said:

$$n\approx 0.328 (kx)^2e^{0.774 kx}$$

As you are interested by the dependence between $x$ and $k$ for a given $n$, you can study, for different values of $n$ the implicit curves given by (1). This is what I have done here for values of $n=2^k, \ k=0 \cdots 20$ (the closest to the origin is for $n=1$).

[image]

Comment: After @g.kov 's answer, I have decided to given up on finding some analytic solution, and thus your analysis is quite helpful, and the final plot you provided is extremely useful for my purposes. From my own numerical simulations, I found a very similar approximation. I appreciate the help, and will mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from @Jean Marie'answer
$$ \dfrac{e^X-1}{X}=k\implies X=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{k}e^{-\frac 1k}\right)-\frac{1}{k}$$
from which
$$x=-\frac{1}{k}\log \left(\frac{X}{n}\right)$$ produces nice and interesting plots (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-%28Log%5B-%281+%2B+k*ProductLog%5B-1%2C+-%281%2F%28E%5Ek%5E%28-1%29*k%29%29%5D%29%2F%282*k%29%5D%2Fk%29%2C%7Bk%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) for $n=2$)

**Edit**

For a shortcut analysis, we could use the bounds

$$-1-\sqrt{2u}-u < W_{-1}(-e^{-(u+1)}) < -1-\sqrt{2u}-\frac{2}{3}u$$ This means that we have
$$X>1+\frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{1}{k}+\log (k)-1\right)+ \sqrt{2\left(\frac{1}{k}+\log
   (k)-1\right)}$$
$$X<\frac{1}{k}+\log (k)+\sqrt{2\left(\frac{1}{k}+\log(k)-1\right)}$$ So, if Lambert function cannot be used, Newton method will converge like a charm starting at the midpoint of the range. Trying for $k=12345$,we should have $10.718 <x< 13.525$ and Newton iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & X_m \\
 0 & 12.121495 \\
 1 & 11.919031 \\
 2 & 11.897543 \\
 3 & 11.897327
\end{array}
\right)$$

We also have
$$\frac{dX}{dk}=\frac 1k\Bigg[1+\frac{1-k}{k \left(W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e^{-1/k}}{k}\right)+1\right)}\Bigg]$$ and for large values of $k$, $\frac{dX}{dk}\sim\frac 1k$. For example, for $k=12345$, the second term in brackets is $0.092$.

In any manner, we can write
$$\frac{dX}{dk}=\frac{X^2}{e^X (X-1)+1}$$

We can also use the expansion
$$W_{-1}(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(-t)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$. This would give
$$X=-\frac{1}{k}-\log \left(\frac{e^{-1/k}}{k}\right)+\log \left(-\log
   \left(\frac{e^{-1/k}}{k}\right)\right)-\frac{\log \left(-\log
   \left(\frac{e^{-1/k}}{k}\right)\right)}{\log \left(\frac{e^{-1/k}}{k}\right)}$$  For $k=12345$, this would give $X=11.902$ which is not bad, in particular if you want to perform sensitivity analysis.

**Comment**

After @g.kov's answer and @Jean Marie's new answer, to make the story short, using $X=k x$, what we need to solve for $X$ is
$$n=-\frac{e^X \Big[X \,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{X}e^{-\frac 1X}\right)+1\Big]}{X}$$ which cannot be inversed.

However, taking logarithms, for $X \geq 1.17$ (corresponding to $n=0$), we almost face a straight line and this explains why  @g.kov's solution is so efficient.

Using series developed around $x=2$ plus series reversion, the simple model (all numbers have been made rational)
$$x_{\text{est}}=\frac{906}{875}+\frac{221 }{1098}t+\frac{154 }{1247}t^2-\frac{27
   }{2875}t^3+\frac{1}{3629}t^4 \quad \text{where} \quad t=\log(n)$$ seems to be decent. Repeating @g.kov calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{\text{est}} \\
 10^1 & 2.04674 \\
 10^2 & 3.78813 \\
 10^3 & 5.85056 \\
 10^4 & 8.01087 \\
 10^5 & 10.2318 \\
 10^6 & 12.6621
\end{array}
\right)$$

With this estimate, one iteration of Newton method should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Claude for the answer! Repeating my comment above on Jean Marie's post,  I was still having trouble in isolating the effect of $k$ for the sake of my problem, and was hoping for some kind of result of the form $x=...O(g(k))$ for some $g(\cdot)$, so I can see how x varies as a function of k. Do you have any suggestions on this? I would thinking something along the lines of a polynomial approximation but haven't had any luck

Comment: Claude,  a big problem: see the remark of @g.kov at the bottam of my answer. How has it been possible ?

Comment: +1. Just a side note (probably not relevant to this particular expression): I'm always feel skeptical and suspicious with polynomials 
for numeric calculations with degree higher than $3$.

Comment: @g.kov. Take care : it is not a curve fit but a series reversion.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align} 
\ln(1+knxe^{-kx})-ne^{-kx}&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Let's introduce an aggregate variable $x_k=k\,x$ and consider

\begin{align} 
f(x_k,n)&=\ln(1+nx_k\exp(-x_k))
-n\exp(-x_k)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
f'(x_k,n)&=
\frac{n\exp(-x_k)(2-x_k+n x_k\exp(-x_k))}{1+n x_k\exp(-x_k)}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
f''(x_k,n)&=
-\frac{n\exp(-x_k)(3+2 n x_k \exp(-x_k)-x_k+n^2 x_k^2\exp(-x_k)^2+n\exp(-x_k))}{(1+n x_k\exp(-x_k))^2}
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Unfortunately, this can not be solved for $x_k$ in terms of the Lambert W function,
but we can iteratively use for example,
[Halley's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method)
for approximation using $x_k=1$ as initial value:

For the given value of $n$
\begin{align}
x_k&=1
,\\
x_k&=F(x_k,n)
,\\
\text{where }\quad
F(x_k,n)&=
x_k-\frac{2f(x_k,n)f'(x_k,n)}{2f'(x_k,n)^2-f(x_k,n)f''(x_k,n)}
.
\end{align}

For $n=1$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
1& 1.170357771616290002056344708\\
2& 1.172153694350020764084170876\\
3& 1.172153696769533591767696701\\
4& 1.172153696769533591767696707\\
5& 1.172153696769533591767696707\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=10$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
1& 1.896366323616900540896745045\\
2& 2.044347353344615923536047462\\
3& 2.045237598213555140104218752\\
4& 2.045237598430951013724790276\\
5& 2.045237598430951013724790276\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=100$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
1& 2.676977597093520446314198800\\
2& 3.629306932322634358319376213\\
3& 3.790023265351929630735197416\\
4& 3.790989232408695901053075975\\
5& 3.790989232643263891789079366\\
6& 3.790989232643263891789079366\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=1000$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
1& 2.941848594014437575855059309\\
2& 4.651983547563005304454022320\\
3& 5.665615157569268469752834587\\
4& 5.847794768505345583727809014\\
5& 5.849066417464094283959333857\\
6& 5.849066417949455069142805365\\
7& 5.849066417949455069142805365\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=10000$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
1& 2.991631201381196147711654450\\
2& 4.942216194436636574135415079\\
3& 6.691925964200960456959570754\\
4& 7.786972044834279373241962071\\
5& 8.009206466615856546298611367\\
6& 8.011339418770442765821907078\\
7& 8.011339420912492089580072226\\
8& 8.011339420912492089580072229\\
9& 8.011339420912492089580072229\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=100000$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\                       
\hline
 1& 2.998911543369285847644408551\\
 2& 4.992053906966172133262219200\\
 3& 6.951670083373696539811777384\\
 4& 8.741555799151739748099970904\\
 5& 9.933088113195797374388449924\\
 6& 10.21577347847871911617793661\\
 7& 10.21987561633406160992976994\\
 8& 10.21987563082686304449920262\\
 9& 10.21987563082686304449920326\\
10& 10.21987563082686304449920326\\
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

For $n=1000000$:
$
\begin{array}{rl}
\text{Iteration}& x_k\\
\hline
 1& 2.999866095952775328866377519\\
 2& 4.998993967002682999509147359\\
 3& 6.993540469412135171118119836\\
 4& 8.961178487137984763660861946\\
 5& 10.78839772824291465235044375\\
 6& 12.08213177637762149050692645\\
 7& 12.44519713978354747687507392\\
 8& 12.45338766190809257143884486\\
 9& 12.45338777270351446760823256\\
10& 12.45338777270351446760850828\\
11& 12.45338777270351446760850828\\                 
\hline\\
\end{array}
$

[image]

---

**Edit**

And you can still get use of the Lambert W function:
the condition for the argument of $\ln(1+knxe^{-kx})$ to be valid
is $xk>-\operatorname{W}(\tfrac1n)$ and you have
a lower boundary $x>-\tfrac1k \operatorname{W}(\tfrac1n)$,
which for large $n$ tends to zero from the left.

**Edit**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @g.kov! This numerical method seems promising and I will likely implement something similar. Just to confirm, is there likely no closed form solution (without involving some strange special functions (even more specialized that the Lambert W))? In that case I may give up looking for something of the sort

Comment: @deeptable: Well, there is some generalized 
version of the Lambert W, which slightly extends the scope of solvable equations,
but I'm not sure that it is applicable in this case. Just use any suitable numerical method.
Or you can always use known solvers, for example, PARI/GP: 
`f(xk,n)=log(1+n*xk*exp(-xk))-n*exp(-xk);`
`solve(xk=1,20,f(xk,1000000))` 
`%3 = 12.45338777270351446760850828`.

Comment: Interesting analysis [+1]

Comment: Thanks again for pointing my error !

Comment: Halley's iteration should be $x_{{n+1}}=x_{n}-\frac{2f(x_{n})f'(x_{n})}{2{[f'(x_{n})]}^{2}-\color{red}{f(x_{n})}f''(x_{n})}$

Comment: @Jean Marie: Right, thanks, MathJax typo ($f'$ instead of correct $f$ in the denominator) fixed, the real calculations were not affected.
Just to clarify, $x_k$ here is the name of the variable, and since there also $n$ involved.
I decided to drop the indices like ${x_k}_{j+1}=F({x_k}_j,n)$
and leave it in more like an iteration in a program  $x_k=F(x_k,n)$.

Comment: I prefer to not interfere with your nice answer. Would you mind to try on a log basis ? Have a look at my comment. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: added semi-log graph, it indeed looks very much like a straight line.

Comment: Have a look at my estimate